# jQuery append() adding at beginning

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I want to turn something like `<sup>1</sup>` into `<sup><a href="..." class="...">1</a></sup>`
I figured the easist way would be to prepend `<a href....>` and append `</a>` but the append is not coming after the content (`1`)...

I know I could do a second `.each()` and store the `1` as a variable and then do `.html()`, but I figure that's not best practice since it involves another loop.

Thanks!!

http://jsfiddle.net/pqzL4/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you might want to look a jQuery [wrapInner](http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/).

```
$('sup').wrapInner('<a href="#"></a>');
```

Which will wrap the text of any sup with a link.

Comment: Thanks! that worked perfectly, do you know why append didn't work in that situation though?

Answer (score 7):

@Daff's answer should solve your problem.  The reason it doesn't work is because as soon as you do:

```
$(this).prev(".article").find("sup").prepend("<a href=\"#references" + (i + 1) + "\" class=\"references\">");
```

It gets added immediately.  Since an unclosed tag is invalid, the browser will "correct" it by closing the tag for you.

Then you try to add a close tag to the end, which is invalid without an open tag so the browser ignores it.

Comment: wow, I wish I could pick both as  the "correct" answer... I asked mostly cause I wanted to know why it didn't work, but wrap did solve my problem. Thank you!

Comment: @maz It's cool. Daff's answer solves the real problem anyway, I'm just explaining why your way doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot append or prepend HTML fragments; you can only work with complete tags.

You're looking for [`wrap`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap).

> **Description**: *Wrap an HTML structure around each element in the set of matched elements.*

Comment: but I'm using prepend().... and append()... could you look at the jsfiddle and tell me what I'm doing wrong.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is "wrapInner()". It takes the contents of one element and wraps it with an element you pass in. Something along the lines of

```
$('sup').wrapInner('<a href...></a>')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(this).prev(".article").find("sup").append('<a>' + $(this).prev(".article").find("sup").text() + '</a>');
```

Comment: if you try it you'll see that doesn't work because it will find more than 1 sup and group it all together so you get `<a href..>12</a>` for both instead of `<a...>1</a>` and `<a ...>2</a>`

Comment: I realized that. I'm updating your fiddle, hang on.

Comment: Shoot, others have beaten me. @Slaks or @Daffs answer is the way to go.